# how can I remove header and footer in Flutter WebView?

Tags: javascript, flutter, flutterwebviewplugin, webview-flutter

This is what I used

[image: 1]

There's this video by Joannes Mike on YouTube I followed on how to remove header and footer in Flutter WebView but it seems flutter had upgraded her library and this functions don't work anymore.

Been at this for days and it seems no recent info is available.

Heres my code

```
import 'package:sportybet_betting_tips/main.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';




class sportybet_tips extends StatefulWidget {
  const sportybet_tips({super.key});

  @override
  State<sportybet_tips> createState() => _sportybet_tipsState();
}


class _sportybet_tipsState extends State<sportybet_tips> 

{
  late final WebViewController controller;
  @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    controller = WebViewController()
    ..loadRequest(Uri.parse('https://accessbettingtips.com/sportybet/'),);
    
    
    //     controller.addJavaScriptChannel(
    //  "document.getElementsByTagName('header')[0].style.display='none'", onMessageReceived: (JavaScriptMessage ) {  });
    //  controller.loadRequest(Uri.parse('http://accessbettingtips.com'),);
    
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: const Text('Sportybet Betting Tips'),
    ),

 body: WebViewWidget(controller: controller),

  
// controller.evaluateJavascript(
    //  "document.getElementsByTagName('header')[0].style.display='none'");
    //  controller.loadRequest(Uri.parse('http://accessbettingtips.com'),);
     

   );

  }
  
  // webview_flutter({required JavaScriptMode JavaScriptMode, required String initialUrl}) {}
}
```

Comment: Please post your code, show what did you try and where exactly the problem is. Currently, your question is too general and doesn't show your effort.

Answer (score -1):

in your onPageFinished method write like that :

```
onPageFinished: (url) async {
      controller.runJavascript("document.getElementsByTagName('header')[0].style.display='none'");          
            },
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this url: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/" + "YOUTUBE_ID".
It does not show complete page but just the video.

"YOUTUBE_ID" is the latest parameter in the url after '?v=xxxxxx'

Comment: This post has nothing to do with embedded YouTube videos.